# Minimize $x+y$ given $(C - 1)xy + x=D$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

> Minimize $x+y$ given $(C - 1)xy + x=D$ where $x$ and $y$ are positive reals

I am looking to derive an equation such that given a constant $C$ and an objective value $D$, I am able to determine the minimum needed combined $x$ and $y$ to reach it.

[objective function with a horizontal plane at D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMZn5.png)

Comment: Do you know about the [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)? The section "single constraint" describes your situation. (This will give you a general robust approach, although you can solve your particular case "by hand", by computing $y$ as a function of $x$ from the constraint equation, then substituting in $x+y$ and maximizing this new function of the single variable $x$).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. We require users to show their attempt. *Show* us ([using MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) how far you went.